# Error Loading atlas Image into Kivy Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

i tried loading all my pictures into my kivy project(which i have actually done successfully before)
and whenever i run the main python file i get this error in the kivy debug session, error line noted in bold

```
...
**[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <atlas://Media/ship-0/battleship>**
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

the use of atlas in my kv code is also shown below

```
<Shooter>:
    source: 'atlas://Media/ship-0/battleship'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 40, 40
    center_x: self.parent.width/2
    y: 0
```

i tried the same image loading process but without the use of atlas and it worked fine. Please what could be the possible issue? Thanks

PS: Directory of the atlas and corresponding image is '...\Space Invaders\Media'

Comment: I would suspect a bad atlas file or perhaps `battleship` is an incorrect image id.

Comment: i am affirmative that the image id is correct and if it were'nt the interpreter would have given a not found sort of error and not a loading error

Comment: You can look at the `ship-0.atlas` file, since it is just a json dict file, and verify that `battleship` is one of the dictionary keys.